# Detecting if a C compiler supports statement expressions

Tags: c, gcc, clang

Is there a way to detect if a compiler (I have a current GCC which has them and an oldish clang which doesn't) implements statement expressions, so that I can do something like this:

```
#ifdef NO_COMPOUND_STATEMENTS
#define MIN(a,b)    ((a)<=(b) ? (a):(b))
#define MAX(a,b)    ((a)>=(b) ? (a):(b))
#else
#define MIN(a,b) ({ __typeof__ (a) _a=(a); __typeof__ (b) _b=(b); _a<_b ? _a : _b; })
#define MAX(a,b) ({ __typeof__ (a) _a=(a); __typeof__ (b) _b=(b); _a>_b ? _a : _b; })
#endif
```

Comment: Um... "Compound statement"? "Compound statement" is a fundamental feature of the language, an therefore of every C compiler since beginning of times. There's no such thing as C compiler that "doesn't  have compound statements". Meanwhile, you seem to be talking about *statement expressions*.

Comment: Could you paste up an example of something that your clang compiler doesn't support?

Comment: The feature you describe as a "compound statement" seems really to be the ability to use a compound statement *as an expression*.  No version of standard C supports this; it is a GCC extension.  Possibly other implementations also support it, but there cannot be any standard way to test specifically for it, because it is not itself standard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As AnT stated in their answer, they aren't part of the standard. Unfortunately, I can't find any evidence of a feature-test macro in GCC either, so your best bet is to check to make sure you're using a `gnu` variant of the C standard and GCC version 3 or later (which is when statement expressions were added)

```
#if !__STRICT_ANSI__ && __GNUC__ >= 3
    /* use statement expressions */
#else
    /* use... something else? */
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

*Statement expressions* (which is what your question seems to be about) is not a standard feature of C language. Neither is `__typeof__`, BTW.

This means that if you want something like that, then the best strategy might be a manually defined macro, which would allow (or disallow) usage of such features in the code. You will manually specify the macro for those specific compilers that implement these non-standard features. (Which is basically just GCC.)

Comment: Note that the standard uses the term "statement expression" to mean something altogether different -- a valid expression used as a complete statement.  Example: `i++;`.

Comment: @John Bollinger: That would be the term "expression statement". That's what the standard uses. Meanwhile, the term "statement expression" is free for taking :)

Comment: Hmm.  You seem to be correct, though footnote 84 actually does use "statement expression" for an expression statement.  One can call that a flaw in the (non-normative) footnote text.  In any case, if you draw this distinction then I think you're coining a term.  [The GCC docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html) do not appear to assign a name to this kind of expression.  With that being the case, I wish you would choose one that is less easily confused with "expression statement".

Comment: _Compound Expression_?

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I'm certainly not the originator of the term. Even if GCC might seem to drift away from this nomenclature at times, it is still used extensively in GCC docs: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Statement-Exprs.html (look through the entire text). I perceive this term as something coined by GCC specifically, not by me.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it like autoconf does this kind of thing: try to compile a chunk and output a macro definition into your config.h (or whatever you have) if the compilation succeeded:

```
echo 'int main(){ int x = ({ puts(""); 32; }); return x; }' > tmp.c
if cc -c tmp.c; then  #-c only to save on linking time
   echo '#define HAVE_STMT_EXPR 1'
fi
```

Comment: My toy project relies on statement expressions too. I decided I wasn't going to support compilers other than gcc, clang and tinycc (all three have both __typeof__ and statement expressions).